# why this function is even function

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous differentiable odd function, and for any
>   $x,y\in R$, such  $$f(x-y)=f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)$$
>
> show that $g(x)$ is an even function.

How can I go about solving this? I think there is a specific function
$$\sin{(x-y)}=\sin{x}\cos{y}-\cos{x}\sin{y}$$

Thanks

Comment: Note that $f(...)$ is odd on both the LHS and the RHS...

Comment: For $f(x) \equiv 0$ (which is an odd function) nothing can be said about $g$ ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't true, even if you assume $f$ is not identically zero.  For instance, when $f(x)=\sin x$, the function $g(x)=\sin x+\cos x$ satisfies the equation but is not even.  More generally, if $g(x)$ is any function that satisfies that equation, so is $g(x)+cf(x)$ for any constant $c$.

However, assuming that $f'(0)\neq 0$ and $g'(0)=0$, you can prove $g$ is even as follows.  First, show that $g(0)=1$ (this is easy).  Next, solve the equation for $g(x)$, and then take the limit as $y\to 0$ using L'Hopital's rule.  This gives you $g(x)=f'(x)/f'(0)$.  Since $f$ is odd, $f'$ is even, so $g$ is even.  More generally, if you don't assume $g'(0)=0$, you can conclude $g(x)=cf(x)+f'(x)/f'(0)$ for some constant $c=g'(0)/f'(0)$.

Comment: I do not get $g(x) = f'(x) / f'(0)$, can you provide the derivation?

Comment: You have $g(x)=(f(x)g(y)-f(x-y))/f(y)$; as $y\to 0$, L'Hopital's rule gives $g(x)=(f(x)g'(0)+f'(x))/f'(0)$.  Since $g'(0)=0$, this gives $g(x)=f'(x)/f'(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

If f (x) not equal 0 then f (x- (-x)) = f (x)[g (x) + g (-x)] = 0.

g (x) = -g (-x)

g is *not* even.

Comment: Where did the "$=0$" come from?